# Parsing string to get comma-separated integer character pairs

Tags: c++, c, string, data-structures, split

I'm working on a project where I'm given a file that begins with a header in this format: `a1,b3,t11, 2,,5,\3,*4,344,00,`. It is always going be a sequence of a single ASCII character followed by an integer separated by a comma with the sequence always ending with `00,`.

Basically what I have to do is go through this and put each character/integer pair into a data type I have that takes both of these as parameters and make a vector of these. For example, the header I gave above would be a vector with `('a',1), ('b',3),('t',11),(',',5)(' ',2),('\',3),('*',4),('3',44)` as elements.

I'm just having trouble parsing it. So far I've:

Extracted the header from my text file from the first character up until before the ',00,' where the header ends. I can get the header string in string format or as a vector of characters (whichever is easier to parse)

Tried using sscanf to parse the next character and the next int then adding those into my vector before using substrings to remove the part of the string I've already analyzed (this was messy and did not get me the right result)

Tried going through the string as a vector and checking each element to see if it is an integer, a character, or a comma and acting accordingly but this doesn't work for multiple-digit integers or when the character itself is an int

I know I can fairly easily split my string based on the commas but I'm not sure how to do this and still split the integers from the characters while retaining both and accounting for integers that I need to treat as characters.

Any advice or useful standard library or string functions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've tagged this with both [c] and [c++]. Can you clarify why? (Note that the best C implementation will not necessarily be the best C++ implementation.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. You should really show us your best effort so far — this helps us calibrate the responses too.  You should also read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  At this stage, you can simply have a function that is given a character array, and a `main()` that calls the function and gives it a character array. If your function might modify the string, do not give it a string literal to work with. The `34400` sequence doesn't seem to match your description; if it was `344,00` it would. Can you clarify that? The `,5` pair is fun.

Comment: Please, Please search before posting.  There are already a plethora of similar questions, **that can be found by searching for** "stackoverflow c++ read file csv" or "stackoverflow c++ read file struct"

Comment: Could you have a string ending `a100,`?  What about `a12300,`?

Comment: @ruakh I just figured either implementation would work for me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry, I did actually mean 344,00 and will edit to fix that. The ',5' would be the ASCII character ',' paired with the number 5. This was another parsing issue I had because I can't simply split by comma since the comma can actually be one of the characters I need to get.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I did search and the splitting by commas wasn't the difficult part for me. The main problem was the fact that there values can be commas themselves and that I need to split these from the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility, of many, would be to store the data in a structure. This uses an array of structures but the structure could be allocated as needed with `malloc` and `realloc`.
Parsing the string can be accomplished using pointers and `strtol` which will parse the integer and give a pointer to the character following the integer. That pointer can be advanced to use in the next iteration to get the ASCII character and integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 100

struct pair {
    char ascii;
    int  integer;
};

int main( void) {
    char input[] = "a1,b3,!0,t11, 2,,5,\\3,*4,34400,";
    char *pt = input;//start with pt pointing to first character of input
    char *end = input;
    int each = 0;
    int loop = 0;
    int length = 0;
    struct pair pairs[SIZE] = { { '\0', 0}};

    //assuming input will always end in 00, ( or ,00,)
    //remove those three ( or 4 ??) characters
    length = strlen ( input);
    if ( length > 3) {
        input[length - 3] = '\0';
    }
    for ( each = 0; each < SIZE; each++) {
        //get the ASCII character and advance one character
        pairs[each].ascii = *pt;
        pt++;
        //get the integer
        pairs[each].integer = strtol ( pt, &end, 10);
        //end==pt indicates the expected integer is missing
        if ( end == pt) {
            printf ( "expected an integer\n");
            break;
        }
        //at the end of the string?
        if ( *end == '\0') {
            //if there are elements remaining, add one to each as one more was used
            if ( each < SIZE - 1) {
                each++;
            }
            break;
        }
        //the character following the integer should be a comma
        if ( *end != ',') {
            //if there are elements remaining, add one to each as one more was used
            if ( each < SIZE - 1) {
                each++;
            }
            printf ( "format problem\n");
            break;
        }
        //for the next iteration, advance pt by one character past end
        pt = end + 1;
    }
    //loop through and print the used structures
    for ( loop = 0; loop < each; loop++) {
        printf ( "ascii[%d] = %c   ", loop, pairs[loop].ascii);
        printf ( "integer[%d] = %d\n", loop, pairs[loop].integer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Another option is to use dynamic allocation.
This also uses sscanf to parse the input. The `%n` will capture the number of characters processed by the scan. The `offset` and `add` variables can then be used to iterate through the input. The last scan will only capture the ascii character and the integer and the return from sscanf will be 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct pair {
    char ascii;
    int  integer;
};

int main( void) {
    char input[] = "a1,b3,!0,t11, 2,,5,\\3,*4,34400,";
    char comma = '\0';
    char ascii = '\0';
    int integer = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int loop = 0;
    int length = 0;
    int used = 0;
    int add = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    struct pair *pairs = NULL;//so realloc will work on first call
    struct pair *temp = NULL;

    //assuming input will always end in 00, ( or ,00,)
    //remove those three ( or 4 ??) characters
    length = strlen ( input);
    if ( length > 3) {
        input[length - 3] = '\0';
    }
    while ( ( result = sscanf ( &input[offset], "%c%d%c%n"
    , &ascii, &integer, &comma, &add)) >= 2) {//the last scan will only get two items
        if ( ( temp = realloc ( pairs, ( used + 1) * sizeof ( *pairs))) == NULL) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem allocating\n");
            break;
        }
        pairs = temp;

        pairs[used].ascii = ascii;
        pairs[used].integer = integer;
        //one more element was used
        used++;
        //the character following the integer should be a comma
        if ( result == 3 && comma != ',') {
            printf ( "format problem\n");
            break;
        }
        //for the next iteration, add to offset
        offset += add;
    }
    for ( loop = 0; loop < used; loop++) {
        printf ( "ascii[%d] = %c   ", loop, pairs[loop].ascii);
        printf ( "value[%d] = %d\n", loop, pairs[loop].integer);
    }

    free ( pairs);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Both of these methods look good but I ended up figuring out a simple solution using a nested while loop. I saved the character then basically iterated through and summed the integer (multiplying by 10 each time to put each digit in the right place) and then added one to skip over the comma and repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have figured out that you can just ignore the last 3 characters, using sscanf will be sufficient.
You can use sscanf to read one character (or getch functions), use sscanf to read an integer and finally even ignore one character.

Comment if you are having problems understanding how to do so.

Comment: Patience!  You'll soon have permission to create comments, as long as you don't add things which are not an answer as if they were an answer.  This is a prime comment — it is not a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, scanf capabilities looks like an eligible answer, isn't it? Maybe I shouldn't have rushed to it before OP clarified his intentions, efforts and main issue. Thanks again.

Comment: There's a fair chance that `sscanf()` (with one or two s's) is part of the solution, but the details will be intricate (note that one field is `,5`) and a general reference to one of the most fiendishly and subtly difficult to use function families really isn't a lot of help.  Yes, in my opinion, you should have waited for clarification.  And you'll soon be able to request it yourself.

Comment: I thought about and tried using sscan but numbers can also count as ASCII characters so just doing sscanf to get %c and then %d didn't seem to work well.